# How to restore a deleted recurrence event instance using Google calendar API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

How can I restore a deleted recurrence event instance using Google calendar API?

I have tried PATCH API for setting status as "**confirmed**". Unfortunately, that didn't work. I am getting "forbidden" error (only for this operation).

Comment: Who is the owner of the event.  Forbiden normally means the user doesnt have permission to do that.

Comment: @DaImTo: I am trying with "googleapis" npm module and scheduling the events in Google Calendar for our customer programatically. I am able to perform other operations like INSERT, UPDATE, PATCH and DELETE using the same Google cloud console credentials. Even I am able to update the status for standalone events. The problem is with updating the status of a recurrence event instance once it gets deleted. Can you please help us to address this issue?

Comment: I dont think you can update anything that has been deleted.

Comment: @DalmTo: Actually I am trying to update the master event of recurrence excluding few instances. So, I am passing the instances that needs to be excluded as EXDATES. Unfortunately, those EXDATES are marked as "Cancelled" by Google. Only when I tried updating those cancelled events status, I am experiencing FORBIDDEN error. So, two questions: a) Is it possible to update master event without having the EXDATE instances getting marked as cancelled? b) Is it possible to update the status of those events?

Answer (score 0):

Use [UPDATE](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) instead of PATCH. Also, it's important to retrieve the instances by the event's iCalUID, which will ensure 'cancelled' (previously deleted) instances are included in the output. Python example:

```
event = cal_service.events().get(calendarId=my_cal_id, eventId=my_google_event_id).execute()

instances = cal_service.events().list(calendarId=my_cal_id, iCalUID=event['iCalUID'],
                                                        showDeleted=True).execute()['items']
for i in instances:
    if i['status'] != 'confirmed':
        i['status'] = 'confirmed'
        cal_service.events().update(calendarId=my_cal_id, eventId=i['id'], body=i).execute()
```